# Why can't i share a file with other applications on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native, instagram

I'm trying to open a file to be linked to another app (Instagram) on my iPhone. I edit this video file so i'm not getting it directly from my camera roll, but i have a link to it locally which i've logged on my physical device below:

uri:

```
"private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/(Long filename).mp4"
```

I've removed the "/private". What i'm trying to to with this is:

```
shareToApp = (uri) => {
        amendedURI = 'file://' + uri;       
        let encodedURL = encodeURIComponent(amendedURI);  
        let instagramURL = 'instagram://library?AssetPath=${' + encodedURL + '}';
        return Linking.openURL(instagramURL);
}
```

but the screen where you share to 'Feed' or 'Stories' displays the last item in my gallery (pic or video), not the video i've passed as the 'uri'

Is there something here which prevents me from achieving this?

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is like `${ ... }` ($ and curly braces part of the string, _not_ template literal)?

Comment: If i try and do this: 'instagram://library?AssetPath=${encodedURL}' then encodedURL isn't recognised as a variable. It just becomes part of the string. I just realised theres a difference between ` and '  . It's making some difference in highlighting encodedURL now! I'll test to see if thats the issue

Comment: if you use backticks it becomes a template string and you can substitute variables using `${variableName}` syntax. if you use regular single/double quotes, the `${...}` will be taken literally which probably not you want.